# Docker + Wordpress - Where do it edit my files?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm working with Docker and I created a docker file (see below) and when it run docker compose up, it works fine. But the problem is I'm not sure:

Where do I edit my files?

I may be wrong, but from research there should be a folder named wp_data with my files in it and when I make a change to those files they should sync with the container.

But the wp_data folder doesn't exist and if I create it, it won't populate with anything.

Can someone help me please?

```
services:
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    #image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

Comment: Do you want to edit  the files at development stage or in production?

Answer (score 3):

You declared 2 docker volumes: `db_data` and `wp_data` in your config.

```
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

So to see those volumes you can: `docker volume ls` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/

But what I would suggest if you do active development and you want to modify files.
Don't use docker volume to store your files but mount your local folder.

Example. Create `wp_data` folder. Then mount that folder in `wordpress` section like

```
  ...
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./wp_data/:/var/www/html
  ...
```

and remove volume from the config file, since you don't need it anymore.

```
volumes:
  db_data:
```